# Android LinkedList lag when removing element

Tags: android, arrays, list, lag

I really need help with this one. I am working with a game and have encountered a problem where it lags everytime an element is getting removed from my lists with objects. I have searched for solutions and found out about using iterators to reduce lag, but still, it lags. I have used both ArrayList and LinkedList, but they both end up with the same result.

This is an example of the code I am using for my lists:

Initialize:

```
private LinkedList<Background> bg = new LinkedList<Background>();
```

Render:

```
for (Iterator<Background> iterator = bg.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Background back = iterator.next();
            if (back.getX()-(-width-1) > 0) {
                if ((back.getX() < width) || (back.getX()+width > 0)) {
                    back.draw(canvas);
                } else {
                    iterator.remove();
                }
            }
        }
```

This is the draw function inside the object class in which back.draw(canvas); is calling from:

```
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    // where to draw the sprite
    Rect destRect = new Rect(getX(), getY(), getX() + spriteWidth, getY() + spriteHeight);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, sourceRect, destRect, null);
    //canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 20, 150, null);
    //Paint paint = new Paint();
    //paint.setARGB(50, 0, 255, 0);
    //canvas.drawRect(20 + (currentFrame * destRect.width()), 150, 20 + (currentFrame * destRect.width()) + destRect.width(), 150 + destRect.height(),  paint);
}
```

Maybe there is something that has to be changed in the MainThread that handles the FPS? Or is there any other solution? I have heard about sets, but can't seem to find any good example try it out.

Something to point out is that I am using Canvas, not OpenGL.
Something else to point out is that each element in the above array has an image size of 800x480. I have tried to reduce the quality of the image, but it doesn't make much of a difference.

Thank you.

Comment: How often do you do this, and how big is the list? Are you sure that the list is the problem and not the draw operation?

Comment: I have two lists that goes through every element. The list in the code above consists of about 4 elements depending on how well the app is removing the images when the should be removed. The other list consists of about 2-3 elements which are the entities in the game. If the draw operation is the problem, what in the draw operation may be the problem? And with draw operation, do you mean the function or something else?

Comment: Such short lists shouldn't cause any problems. Look into what is going on in `back.draw(canvas)`.

Comment: I've added the code I am using for the draw function in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its probably with the amount of computation you are doing in draw. I am sure its nothing to do with the collection you use.

Comment: I tried minimizing the computing in my render function by moving the big blocks of code to separate functions and linking them to the render function, but that didn't work. How am I supposed to decrease the computing?

Comment: In my case, i do the computations before, when initializing or when fetching the data. Then either i create a Picture object and store the picture in a list. Finally when i need to draw I just use canvas.drawPciture. That way the view is rendered pretty fast and memory required is low

Answer (score 0):

Given the code you have posted I would say that a `LinkedList` and an `Iterator` to remove items is certainly the fastest. But you also have to take the other usage of the list into account.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. Doesn't seem to fix the problem I am having. The others said something about the draw operation. I am curious if they mean the rendering function or something else, though.

Comment: If you see the problem in the code above, then try to minimize the wotk you do while drawing the background. Replace by a single color rectangle for example. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean with "wotk", but what I am doing in the code is making the background recreate itself after another and move to the left so it creates a scrolling motion. It works really well, but the only problem is that it lags when I am making a background remove itself after it has moved out of the screen and is no longer needed.

Comment: It should be "work" ;) Make sure that you do not scale the image every time you draw. That can cause huge overhead. Hm, but it sounds strange. The list operation should not be able to do that.

Comment: I am not scaling the images whatsoever. :) The list operation is not moving the images, it handles them so there can be several of the same type.

Comment: The draw operation where you specify the dest rect may scale.

Comment: Oh, okay. I'll look into that asap.

Comment: I removed some code that was used for animation using sourceRect, but it didn't help. I don't think the problem has to do about the size of the image.